# Qt: How know when QWebEnginePage is loaded (incl. JS)?

Tags: c++, qt

In QT 5.7 the QWebEnginePage is signalling loadFinished once the HTML has been loaded:

> This signal is emitted when the page finishes loading content. This signal is independent of script execution or page rendering. ok will indicate whether the load was successful or any error occurred.

In my case I'm using ReactJS, so the page hasn't actually *rendered* at this point. How can I know when the page has rendered (all initial JavaScripts have finished executing)?

Comment: There's no way for any browser to know this. Your best bet is to add something to your script that signals when the loading is complete.

Comment: Are there any recommended signalling mechanisms to communicate between Qt and JS?

Comment: There may be other ways, but a WebSocket connection between the Javascript and Qt would do the trick. Qt provides [QWebSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html) for the C++ part of your application.

Comment: Or with a [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html), see [QWebEnginePage::setWebChannel()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#setWebChannel-1)